# Do Goldstone modes, by definition, have to be low-energy or long wavelength?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, symmetry-breaking, wavelength, goldstone-mode

For a spontaneously broken continuous global symmetry, there exist Goldstone modes for which the dispersion relation is such that as the momentum or the wavenumber goes to zero the energy or frequency also goes to zero. Does this mean that Goldstone modes necessarily have to be low-energy or long-wavelength excitations?

Comment: The statement about no mass gap is by definition about $k \to 0$. The dispersion relation ($\omega = ck$ in the relativistic case) typically holds only at low energies, and may be more complicated at higher energies. Furthermore, at higher energies, it may couple to other modes, and there can even be self-coupling. Then the Nambu-Goldstone mode loses its identity.

Comment: In a Lorentz-symmetric model, given a state with arbitrarily low but nonzero momentum, you can apply a Lorentz boost to make its momentum arbitrarily large (energy arbitrarily high, wavelength arbitrarily short). If it was a single-particle state before the boost, then it still is after the boost.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly So your answer is that there is no reason why a Goldstone mode should be low-energy because that's not a meaningful Lorentz-invariant statement.

Comment: @AronBeekman I don't see the reason why a complicated dispersion relation cannot satisfy $\omega\to0$ as $k\to 0$. For example, consider $\omega\sim \sin(ka)$ does satisfy the desired property despite being apparently not so simple. Also, there is no reason that a Godstone mode cannot have interactions, self or not.

Comment: No, I agree. Of course NG modes exist at higher energies. What I meant to say is that there is some energy scale above which one can no longer speak of 'a mode' (more precisely a sharp pole in the Green's function). This energy scale varies from system to system.